# How to ensure right set of data in objects returned from LINQ to DataSet Query

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I'm new in C# and OO as a whole, please forgive me if this question sounds silly.

What I want to do is to obtain and loop through the the returned object for a field named CDNumber  in the a DataTable named CD of a DataSet named CollectionsDataSet.

Not all Rows in CD has a value, some are null.

So I write this LINQ query

```
Var CDNumbers =
    From CDNumber in CollectionsDataSet.CD.AsEnumerable()
    Where CDNumber.Field<int>("CDNumber") > 0
    Select CDNumber.Field<int>("CDNumber") > 0
    ;

For each (CDNumberRow in CDNumbers) {
    If (CDNumberRow > 0) {
        MessageBox.Show(CDNumberRow.ToString());
    }
}
```

Problem is that only two of the three non null data are outputted.

Comment: what are the CDNumbers in the dataset?

Comment: They are designed as nullable integer field in the database. The DataTable is filled with the data from the field. There are about 7 rows in the table. The first two from that field has values 10 and 10, then nulls, and the last has value 5. But I see only the first 10s outputted. I hope that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below

```
Var CDNumbers =
    From CDNumber in CollectionsDataSet.CD.AsEnumerable()
    Where CDNumber.Field<int?>("CDNumber") != null
    Select CDNumber.Field<int?>("CDNumber");
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much Damith. I had been at this for a whole day. Can you please tell me why mine did not work and yours did?

Comment: you selecting `CDNumber.Field<int>("CDNumber") > 0` that will return true or false. finally you have list of true or false values :)

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure how to accept but I clicked the mark sign under the votes. I hope that is how you accep(. Thanks again.